# MobaXterm builtin shell (zsh/bash 64bit) strange behavoiur

Tags: bash, 64-bit, zsh, mobaxterm

Using builtin terminal from MobaXterm, and executing commands like `curl` or `ssh` works couple of times and later produce no output at all. Anyone had similar experience? My problems started after upgrading to latest version of Moba (23.0).

[image: 64bit problem]

[image: 64bit problem 2]

P.S: on 32bit version `curl` and `ssh` freezes Moba and even CTRL-D / CTRL-C does not help.

[image: 32bit freeze]

Running MobaXterm with administrator privilages does not change anything.  Rebooting does not change anything but "resetting" tries to block. Curl and SSH from `pwsh` or WSL works fine.

Using Windows 10 PRO version 21H2 (compilation 19044.2604)

Comment: Which Win version? What means "resetting tries to block"? What exactly is being blocked? Please don't answer in comments, but edit your question to keep it up-to-date and everything relevant readily available.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) [Edit] your question and copy&paste the output *as text*  and format it as code blocks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ".... but "resetting" tries to block."?

Comment: @Ramhound I'mean that when I reset my PC and starting MobaXterm again to execute curl and/or ssh output will be the same. Couple of times it will work as expected and after that Moba still going to execute command successfully but there will be no output for curl and no connection for ssh - like on attached pictures.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Windows 10 PRO version 21H2 (compilation 19044.2604)

Comment: "Please _**don't** answer in comments_, but edit your question to keep it up-to-date and everything relevant readily available."

Comment: The author of this application will reply to your question.  He *might* not be willing to help for a free version.. but then again, he *might*.

Comment: Have you tried to return MobaXterm to the version that worked?